# Why is the default speed of a CPU fan high?

Tags: fan

When a CPU fan first receives power (or if no PWM speed is present), why is the default speed High?

Answer (score 1):

Because if the default was low, then the CPU would overheat very quickly, and cause a thermal shutdown. Even booting Windows would generate sufficient core load to generate heat. Heat would be hard to dissipate with a low-speed HSF. Even with a large heat sink, you still need fans to move air over the fins.

Comment: Actually, this is not entirely true. Fans ramp up at boot as part of a test to ensure that the fan is working. During boot, yes the boot process itself uses all CPU power too. This is very evident in servers, but is not limited to servers only. Every piece of complex machinery that can't fail will have a self test at the start. Even cars do.

Comment: @LPChip Do motherboards provide high PWM to the fans at startup or do they leave them floating?